# Amiga OS3.9 unable to run iGame error #8000000B

Tags: amiga

AMIGA CDTV, 68030 MMU, no FPU, KS 3.1.4, WB3.9 + BBs, MUI3.8, Required Libs.

I followed all the requirements swapping guigfx with non-FPU equivalent and I'm not able to get iGame to run. When FPU is enabled in WinUAE (68882) iGames works as expected (on both versions FPU and NONFPU of guigfx.library). Now, since I wanted to use frontend for WHDLoad on my real Amiga (030 no FPU) does it mean I'm stuck?

Did anyone get it running without an FPU? If not, what other frontend can I use for convenience (WHDLoadMenu is there but rather simple).

[image: The top-left fragment of a screenshot; in the corner, there is an error dialog box ‘Software Failure’ with the message: ‘iGame: Program failed (error #8000000B). Wait for disk activity to finish.’ and two buttons, ‘Suspend’ and ‘Finish’. In the window below, there are three floppy disk icons, labelled ‘f’, ‘TMP’ and ‘DATA’, and three more icons covered by the error dialog. To the right of the icons, there is an empty window entitled ‘iGame’.]

Comment: Why are you running 3.9 on 3.1.4 KS?  3.1.4 WB would be a better bet

Comment: This is purely experimental, was planning to burn custom ROMs for it, but then my Pistorm arrived. I have a CPU socket rework to do then I will be able close the lid hopefully for years to come.

Comment: Looks like you might have to try with a 3.2 ROM soon. :)

Comment: Yup, waiting for my copy to arrive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved the issue by downloading the package again from Aminet: https://aminet.net/package/dev/misc/guigfxlib_nofpu

I have used one of the online tutorials while setting it up and I believe the library I had problem with came from that source, but different than Aminet.